# .First() does not execute; win7 Rgui

Tags: r

With this in .Rprofile (first line copied from ?Startup examples):

```
.First <- function() cat("\n   Welcome to R!\n\n")
foo <- "bar"
```

I do not see the Welcome text.  The following shows that .Rprofile executes.

```
ls()
[1] "foo"
```

Apparently `.First()` does not execute.  Any idea why not?

I'm running in an Rgui console on win7pro with R v3.6.1 x64.

I already learned that I will not be able to do what I wanted to do in .First(), but I still want to know why it is not even executing.  I might want to use it for something in the future.  I haven't made any fancy configuration changes, and I launch the console from a shortcut to Rgui.exe.

Comment: With those two lines in my `~/.Rprofile` file, I see the welcome message and can access `foo`'s value. Is it possible that `foo` is left over from a previous troubleshooting step, and the file you think is the right Rprofile file is in fact not being read? Try changing the value of `foo`, restart R, and see if the changes work. (Granted, this is win10, but I doubt that that is the cause.)

Comment: I checked that before I posted.  In fact, I had some other stuff in .Rprofile that I removed to simplify my post, and that stuff did go away.

Comment: Did you check by directly adding `cat("\n   Welcome to R!\n\n")` line to `.Rprofile` instead of a adding it as a function ?

Comment: Putting it outside of the function makes it show up.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:  Early on I had bad code in .First().  While troubleshooting I cleared the workspace with

```
rm(list=ls())
q('yes')
```

That way the assignment `foo<-"bar"` more clearly showed that .Rprofile was executing.  What I didn't realize was that the bad .First() got saved in some hidden environment in .RData.  After that, no matter what I did with .First() in .Rprofile, it always got replaced with the bad one.  To solve the problem, I just needed to delete .RData.

Update:  .First() does not go into a hidden environment, but the starting dot makes it hide from ls().  To exit with a completely clear workspace, the code would be:

```
rm( list=ls(all.names=T) )
q('yes')
```

That's a lot of typing.  In the future, I think I'll just delete .RData.

To me this seems a lot like a bug.  Anytime you change .First() in .Rprofile, you need to delete .RData from every folder where you use R or execute `rm(.First)` and `q('yes') in every folder.  That just begs for something to be missed.